# Make javascript script in css

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make this in pure css:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Bloater/pen/YzGJZxR)

and I want to make the same thing but in css.
this is my css:

```css
.text{
  --a: calc(var(--a);*0.82+(1.5-var(--b);)/10);
  --b: calc(var(--b);+var(--a););
  transform: scale(var(--b););
}
```

It doesn't work.
I've tried soo many things and none of them have worked.
Please help!

> ### All the information I went through to get that non working css:
>
> > [CSS Variables - The var() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_variables.asp)
> >
> > [Keep Math in the CSS | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/keep-math-in-the-css/)

Comment: The snippet doesn't work

Comment: ^ true, + too many semicolons in CSS calc??

Answer (score 0):

First, your css code is quite messy. Semicolons (;) are used for each propery in css file.
Let me fix your code

```
body{
  --bounce: 100; //create the variables first on parent element
  --size: 100;
}

.text{
  --bounce: calc(var(--bounce) * 0.82 + (1.5 - var(--size) / 10));
  --size: calc(var(--bounce) + var(--size));
  transform: scale(--size);
}
```

Please note, operator sign '+', '-', '*', and '/' must have 1 extra space between two variables or numbers.

Comment: This doesn't work. i  tried it in a temporary snippet